# Output HTML with special characters (μ) in C#

Tags: c#, html, special-characters

I am using C# to generate HTML tables with the special character (μ) via the following code:

```
string text1 = "100 μs";
string text2 = "100 \u00B5s";
string text3 = "100 &#xb5s";

string[] lines = { "<html>", "<body>", text1, text2, text3, "</body>", "</html>" };

string curFile = @"C:\SpecialCharacter.html";

System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(curFile, lines);
```

And the output HTML's source looks like the following:

```
<html>
<body>
100 Î¼s
100 Âµs
100 &#xb5s
</body>
</html>
```

with the last one actually displaying correctly (100 µs) in a browser. I am wondering if there's a better way to do this. Namely, is there a way to actually see "100 µs" in the HTML source code (and display correctly in a browser)? I know that's possible if I write HTML by-hand, but I am not sure how to achieve that via C#.

Thanks.

Comment: For anyone wondering why `text1` and `text2` are different in the output, it's because `text1` specifies U+03BC (Greek Small Letter Mu) whereas `text2` specifies U+00B5 (Micro Sign).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, [`File.WriteAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92e05ft3.aspx) encodes text using UTF-8 but omits the Unicode [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), which will confuse some browsers. To help those browsers out, one option is to include the byte order mark by explicitly specifying [`Encoding.UTF8`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.utf8.aspx) as the encoding:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(curFile, lines, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Another option is to include a `<meta>` tag that specifies UTF-8 as the encoding:

```
string head = "<head><meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'></head>";
// ...
string[] lines = { "<html>", head, "<body>", text1, text2, text3, "</body>", "</html>" };
```